# .htaccess 500 Internal Error even though rules are correct

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues with .htaccess. The issue is that my RewriteRule seems to be invalid even though I have used the same exact one several times before.
The .htaccess rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule api/(.*) api.php?method=$1
```

The issue is that when I visit my website, I get met with a 500 Internal Server error instantly. I tried editing the file to this:

```
Deny from all

#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule api/(.*) api.php?method=$1
```

and I got `permission denied` (**Expected behavior**), so everything should work? I have no idea what is wrong with my htaccess file.
I have tried doing the following:
- Restart apache using `service apache2 restart`
- What I said above, try a simple rule that **will** work if everything is correct and comment out the rest
- Writing the same rule in another file and replacing the text in my .htaccess file with that (I read somewhere that there could be "invisible" characters that .htaccess did **not** like at all)

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the destination path your rule rewrites to otherwise you will get an infinite internal rewrite loop since your Rewrite pattern `api/(.*)` also matches the path `/api/api.php` .

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api\.php [NC]
RewriteRule api/(.*) api.php?method=$1
```

Comment: The error shows as following: [link](https://hastebin.com/iwepubizan.coffeescript)
I realize now what the error is, but I had never read the error log before as someone told me .htaccess errors don't get stored anywhere. Thank you very much though!